# Will Oracle single processor licence database utilise all the processors in a Dell Poweredge 920 server?

Tags: oracle

We have an Oracle database licence for single processor. But we are now going to purchase a Dell Poweredge 920 server with 4 physical processors. can we install the same single processor licensed oracle in the server?Is there any way to install Oracle such that it will utilise all the 4 processors in the server? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not a deinitive answer, but as I have experienced oracle I suspect it might work well with all processors but you're in for a heavy penalty for violating the license-agreement once they find out....

Comment: Even if you could, this would violate your license.

Comment: I think this question is more suited for [DBA StackExChange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) or even [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about). This has nothing to do with programming